# How to know table to reference when creating json web token in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to implement JSON wen token in Django. I have been following tutorial from [this source](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-rest-framework-jwt-tutorial/) I have installed and configured all the necessary requirements.

To obtain user's token, here is the curl example:

```
$ curl --request POST \
      --url http://localhost:8000/jwt-auth/ \
      --header 'content-type: application/json' \
      --data '{"username": "myusername", "password": "mypass"}'

      {"token": "YOUR_JWT_TOKEN"}
```

Here is my code for making call

```
import requests

item = { "username": "admin", "password": "admin"}
resp1 = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/auth-jwt/", 
               data=json.dumps(item),
               headers={
                       "Content-Type":"application/json",
                       "Accept": "application/json"
                      }
 )
print (resp1.status_code)
#print (resp1.content)
content = json.loads(resp1.content)
print(content)
#print(content['status'])
```

My issues:

When I run the above code, it returns error

> non field error: unable to login with provided credentials

What does this mean. which table do I have to create to use their credentials. Currently I have users **nancy** on **auth_user** table.

Consequently, a similar issue [has been resolved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429477/django-using-tokenauthentication-non-field-errors-unable-to-log-in-with-p?rq=1) but I cannot get it to work.

What does the error mean, and what is the next step in solving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my problem. I need to create a superuser account as per

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
```

so running this syntax squentially at command prompts solves my problem.

```
 python manage.py makemigrations
 python manage.py migrate
 python manage.py createsuperuser
 python manage.py runserver
```